# Why Sphinx CALL KEYWORDS ignores stopwords?

Tags: sphinx, stop-words

I have an index with stopwords set up.

I execute CALL KEYWORDS ('word1 stopword word2', 'my_index') and expect to see only two tokens: word1, word2, but I receive three tokens: word1, stopword, word2.

Why it is so? How I can make it work as expected ?

Comment: Is the stopwords definitely enabled on the active live index? eg you added it to the config file, but have not regenerated the index, and loaded it into sphinx.   Perhaps test with 'indextool' ?

Comment: How I can check that they are enabled ?

Comment: The output of `indextool --dumpheader <SPH-FILE>` should mention the stopwords if its being used.

Comment: @barryhunter it is empty index (template) and used only to build excerps (call snippets), so indextool can not help me, because there is no data and so no sph file

Comment: Ekk. Can only guess its a bug then. Wonder if its expectd that would be using an index, so code to load the stopwords only works from index. can't do it direct from config? sphinxsearch.com/bugs/